# Adding multiple gestures to a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, gestures

I am trying to make a button for a simple app which can respond to a single tap, a double tap (i.e. tap-tap, not two finger tap) and a long press (i.e. tap and hold down). I have looked at options regarding multiple touches on a view, but this is a button, and the solution does not work, even with changing the provided code for the button. I have tried many different strategies, but the two main ones that my efforts have focused around are as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];

longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
oneTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
twoTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

[oneTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:twoTap];
[twoTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPress];

[self.recordButton addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[self.recordButton addGestureRecognizer:oneTap];
[self.recordButton addGestureRecognizer:twoTap];
}
```

In this instance, the self.recordButton is simply referring to the name of the button. This UIButton instance in the header file is linking to the button, so that isn't the problem. Additionally, the three actions (i.e. @selector(longPress:)) are defined later in the implementation.

The other is this:

```
-(IBAction)record:(id)sender {
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];

longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
oneTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
twoTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

[oneTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:twoTap];
[twoTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPress];

[self.recordButton addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[self.recordButton addGestureRecognizer:oneTap];
[self.recordButton addGestureRecognizer:twoTap];
}
```

Record is linked to the button I am trying to get a response from.

The last two things to note are:

- The button action worked when it only took one touch (the long press and double tap are adding functionality), so there is not a problem with linking the button to the method Record
- The long press and double tap gestures are simply used for segues (I think that is the right word). Basically, those two gestures are used to go to different views

So my question is, how do I do this? I mainly just needed to know the general theory behind adding multiple gestures to a button.

Comment: Don't use UIButton, subclass UIview. It'll make this a lot easier.

Comment: So you're saying make my own subclass of uiview?

Comment: Correct, for reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html